# Find a Class inside a List of Classes with java stream

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm going to find a class in a list of Classes (`List<Class<?>>`) with java streams:

```
Class cls = classList.stream().filter(clazz -> clazz.getName().startsWith("MyName")).findAny().orElse(null);
```

A class with the name `MyNameClass` exists in the list, but the value of `cls` is null at the end. Is there anything wrong in the `filter()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `.getSimpleName`, `.getName` returns fully qualified name of the class with package in it. For example, `String.class.getName()` returns "java.lang.String".

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.getSimpleName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) in your *filter*

```
classList.stream()
         .filter(clazz -> clazz.getSimpleName().startsWith("MyName"))
         .findAny()
         .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Not a problem at all. But if you need the question to be re-opened you can post your concerns/queries [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).